# windows programming: grab audio without the driver supporting "Stereo Mix

Tags: windows, winapi, audio

Grabbing the system audio using 'Stereo Mix' is easy, but most modern drivers don't support that anymore. Steam local streaming somehow managed to do it without, i can clearly hear other apps audio output while streaming an arbitrary game.

How does steam do that? Did they silently install a driver? Is there any other way of grabbing system audio?

From Windows 7 and up that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Vista and later you can use WASAPI. It allows to use loopback for any output device, just use an output as an input with the AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK flag for this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370875(v=vs.85).aspx